# How specific should our tags be?

Tags: discussion, tags

Many of our tags are aimed at covering broad, general categories, rather than  using more, specific tags of limited scope.

For example, we have

- [modifiers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modifiers) instead of [array-modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-modifier), [mirror-modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mirror-modifier) [subsurf-modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subsurf-modifier), etc.
- [file-format](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-format) instead of [obj](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/obj), [fbx](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fbx), [collada](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/collada), etc.

Is this good or bad?

Would it be more useful to have smaller, more specific tags (e.g. [knife-tool](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knife-tool))? Or is there current strategy better? And if so, why?

If smaller tags are more useful, how specific should they be?

---

As an example on another SE site, [GD](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags?page=4&tab=popular) has many specific tags referring to a kind of tool or file format.

<sub>I couldn't find a good way to search for "specific tags", but if you poke around you'll see tags like [jpg](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jpg) and [pen-tool](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pen-tool).</sub>

Comment: With regards to your point about GD's tags, those tags aren't as vague as ours and are actually needed IMO, for example, the pen tool is a major part of an image app as opposed to the knife tool for us which can fall under `modeling` and knowing what image format you are exporting to is also good when looking at filesize or quality etc as opposed to having `exr` or `obj` for us which is basically useless.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17705/parenting-to-an-array-end-cap, just interesting timing for that new tag (modifier-array) to pop up.

Comment: i think its more friendly to new users if the tags are general.

Comment: Related http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/286/how-should-we-deal-with-tags-about-other-software/289#289